# What is the React way of displaying a tooltip on range sliders?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

What is the `ReactJS` of showing the current value on input type range as a tool-tip on the  thumb of the slider.

I'm aware that it can be done using `jQuery` plugins but I want to avoid using plugins. Pure React+HTML+CSS is preferred. Javascript/jQuery can used but plugins need to be avoided.

Comment: React just emits HTML. You can use whatever you'd like. There isn't a standard way of doing it. Please provide the code you've tried and what you're stuck on.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I cannot provide code. For this reason I was expecting some downvotes as well. Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: I presented a small tooltip example on another question some months ago. Hope you can get something out of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310390/should-reacts-flux-stores-be-a-snapshot-of-the-whole-state-of-a-gui/27312082#27312082

Comment: "Find a tool/component" or requests to write code are generally closed/held on StackOverflow.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm not asking for any tool/component or written code. Just look at the answer by Deepak. It was helpful.

Comment: There is no "React" way. React just emits HTML -- you can use any technique you want and any CSS tricks or plug-ins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var InputRange = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        points: 5
      };
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({points: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function() {
        return <input 
          type="range" 
          name="points"
          min="0" 
          max="10"
          title={this.state.points}
          value={this.state.points}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />;
    }
});
```

You can do something similar like above. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/906kq0pw/1/).

Comment: Thank you Deepak. This is very much similar to the requirements. But I need the tool-tip to be shown only when the thumb (not the track) is dragged or active.